# Python Error ValueError: View function did not return a response

Tags: python, flask

My application when it runs the url http://localhost:81/ip_update/00178r it of the error ValueError: View function did not return a response.
I am unable to solve, if anyone can help me I will be very grateful

```
def ip_update (client):
    ip = request.remote_addr
    if 'r' in client:
        customer = cliente.rstrip ('r')
        urllib2.urlopen ('http://localhost:85/administration/ip_update/' + client + '/' + ip)
        time.sleep (3)
    else:
        server = 'localhost'
        port = 3306
        login = root
        password = 'password'

        mdb.connect con = (host = server, port = port = user login, passwd = password, use_unicode = True)
        cur = con.cursor ()

        cur.execute ("SELECT FROM tar_cliente ebas.tarefa WHERE tar_status = 'processing' and tar_cliente = '" + client $

        if cur.rowcount == 0:
            Data2 data = ()
            server = data2 ['clients'] [customer] ['server']
            urllib2.urlopen ('http://' + server + '/administration/ip_update/' + client + '/' + ip)
            time.sleep (3)
            return 'request for ip received for updating client code' + client
        else:
            return 'denied updating, client operation underway'
```

Comment: which line are you getting the error? and can you please post the complete traceback?

Comment: The value you send to `urlopen()` cannot have spaces in the URL; I've removed them on the assumption you were told by Stack Overflow you cannot include such URLs in your text. They are fine in a code block.

Comment: Can you also please clean up the code some more? Your `Data2 data = ()` line is not valid Python, for example. Your code, as posted, cannot possibly run.

Answer (score 2):

Your function returns `None` when the `if` test is true:

```
if 'r' in client:
    customer = cliente.rstrip ('r')
    urllib2.urlopen ('http: // localhost: 85 / administration / ip_update /' + client + '/' + ip)
    time.sleep (3)
```

You need to return a response in that case too. There is no point in using sleep here; all you are doing is delaying returning something to the browser.

Comment: @JeanEduardo: that's what I am saying; you are not returning a valid response there. Return a `make_response()` result or a string, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the problem is not developed this application and do not know programming in python, could you tell me how it would be the right way to do this?

Comment: If you don't know programming in Python, *start with a tutorial*. We'll be here all day figuring out how much you do and don't know otherwise. I cannot help you if you don't at least know the basics.